# MySQL: I want to insert file directories that have backslashes but when i look at the column i see no back slashes

Tags: mysql

I need to insert file directories into a column but when i select (*) after inserting them all the back slashes have gone. does anyone know how i can do this. it is not possible for me to escape the slashes as i have thousands of records. I thought mysql required the user to do this using a remove_slases or something in php

Comment: You should be using either prepared statements or `mysql_real_escape_string`. Either of these will deal with backslashes and other special characters properly.

Comment: Use: mysqli_real_escape_string(), or PDO for handling this kind of inputs, for PDO http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php

Comment: Im not using PHP. just pure Mysql though and when i look at the columns afterwards theres no '\'s

Comment: please show some real sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way to do this in MySQL is by setting the `NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES` SQL mode. Do this for the session with `SET SESSION sql_mode='NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES';`

As such:

```
mysql> SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode;
+--------------------+
| @@SESSION.sql_mode |
+--------------------+
|                    |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select 'don\t';
+------+
| don    |
+------+
| don    |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET SESSION sql_mode='NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select 'don\t';
+-------+
| don\t |
+-------+
| don\t |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

This allows you to insert c:\bla\tla\bla without the \b or \t being interpreted as a string literal. Also take a look at `QUOTE()` if you need 'escaping' alike mysql_real_escape_string

More information at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_backslash_escapes